# Prevent a line of source code from showing

Tags: php, html

How to hide this html line, that will not appear for the user in inspect element or view source.

```
<input type="hidden" name="kda" value="<?php echo $code;?>">
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that - everything you send to the browser can eventually be read and stored somehow.

What you can do instead, however, is using a session to store this information. Then, only a session identifier will be sent to the browser (and back to the server) while your sensitive information can stay on the server.

Comment: Note that this requires a server-side interpreter!

Comment: OP is using php as that's how he's filling the var, no?

Comment: OK how can I use $_SESSION to store more than one

Comment: $_SESSION is an array - you can store multiple values by using different keys, e.g. `$_SESSION['first'] = 'somedata';`, `$_SESSION['second'] = 'otherdata';`. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp for more details

Comment: @winSharp93 Can I use it like this `$_SESSION['$name'] = '$code';`

Comment: @KlausJasper: If you want to store the actual contents of the variable, you'll have to leave out the 's. Just do a simple assignment.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort!

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to hide HTML from view source. Any HTML gets sent to the client and can be viewed in view source. Try storing it in `$_SESSION`, a PHP superglobal. It gives the user a cookie that tells PHP where to look to find that user's information in `$_SESSION`.

`$_SESSION` is an array. That means you can store `$_SESSION['pies_bought'] = 7` and `$_SESSION['cakes_bought'] = 3`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

If you "hide" it, it won't work.
You could surround in PHP comment so it's stripped when the server renders the page, but I think you are asking to hide  the value of this hidden form field, and that you can not do as you are suggesting.
You could post the "viewable" form fields to another php script that then adds this "confidential" key, and then submits the form wherever it's going.
You could, upon submission of form, call an ajax request to get the value and submit all at once.

Many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

Set this flag as a PHP variable instead of actually including the `hidden` input field in the form.

Comment: Just set `$_SESSION['kda']=(result of code())` as has been suggested by @travis-gd? I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use encryption if you still want to use it as a query parameter in your form otherwise session is your best bet.

```
<input type="hidden" name="kda" value="<?php echo some_php_crypt_function($code);?>">
```

When you receive `kda` on the server,just decrypt it and get the value.

This link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php has examples of how to use encryption/decryption in php.