# Hide values in hidden input

Tags: php

I have some hidden inputs, however, if you view the source code, you're still able to see the value saved in the input.

How can I hide the values from the public? Encrypt then decrypt? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store them as session variables if you want them hidden completely, but even then, with the right applications you can view/change these.

Comment: same question is asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001849/how-to-hide-values-in-hidden-fields and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439146/prevent-a-line-of-source-code-from-showing